# React js, add event listener on scroll not working. Help me to solve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna add event listener when user scrolling in my web app, but not working

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        let scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        let header = document.getElementById("topBar");
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => { 
            scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

            console.log(scrollPosition)
        });
}
```

can you guys help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: please define "not working"

Comment: i mean, my code ```console.log(scrollPosition)``` not executed when user scrolling the app in browser

Comment: It should work, just paste `window.addEventListener...` into browser console and it logs properly. Issue lies somewhere else, try restarting your react project and make sure it gets updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
   let header = document.getElementById("topBar");
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFunction}
}

scrollFunction = () => {
  console.log(window.scrollY)
}
```

Comment: can you create a https://codesandbox.io to help show the issue?